# Controlling a sum of L^2 norms

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose we have functions $\psi_n:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $\psi_n \geq 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \psi_n(x) \leq 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Is it true that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \|\psi_nf\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R})} \leq C \|f\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}$ for some uniform constant $C > 0$? This is easy if you replace $L^2$ with $L^1$ just using Tonelli. Another way to view this question is the following. Consider the map $\psi:L^2(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow L^2(\mathbb{R})^{\mathbb{N}}$ given by $\psi(f) = (\psi_1 f, \psi_2 f, ...)$. Is $\psi$ a bounded operator considered as $\psi:L^2(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \ell^1(\mathbb{N},L^2(\mathbb{R}))$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pick any $(a_n)_{n \ge 0} \in \ell^2 \setminus \ell^1$: e.g. let $a_n = n^{-1}$. Let $f = \sum_{n \ge 0} 1_{[n, n+1)} a_n$ and let $\psi_n = 1_{[n, n+1)}$. Then
$$\|f\|_{L^2} = \|a_n\|_{\ell^2} < \infty$$
but $$\sum_{n \ge 0} \|\psi_n f \|_{L^2} = \sum_{n \ge 0} |a_n| = \infty.$$